# Trying to send a tar over ssh but its being decompressed when sent

Tags: ssh, tar

Im trying to tar a directory and send it over ssh to another server, but I want it to be sent with tar format not decompressed as the following script does

```
tar -czf - Documents | ssh user@server tar -xzf - -C server_backup_directory/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not what the script does. It archives and compresses the directory; sends it over in .tar.gz format; *then* decompresses it once it's already on the destination server.

So if you don't want the last part to happen, just change the decompression command `tar -x` into something which doesn't decompress, usually `cat`:

```
tar -czf - Documents | ssh user@server "cat > Documents.tar.gz"
```

(Be sure to use quotes so that the entire command, including `>` redirection, is run on the server.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `scp` instead.

The command you are running will decompress the file as you're explicitly telling it to do.

An example of `scp` would be:

```
tar -czf Documents.tar Documents/ && scp Documents.tar user@server:. && rm -f Documents.tar
```